# Python-Multiple user inputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, calculator, infinite

I am trying to take user input multiple times on python and then taking its sum.

Taking user input multiple times means i need a new variable each time to store the user input.I need a program which can take infinite user inputs and ofcourse its impossible to assign a new variable to infinite user inputs and add them up.
**Is there any built-in function in python which can keep on adding the values itself?**

Here is my code.It doesnt give me the sum because of sentinel(I dont understand why).
Please help.

```
var = int(raw_input("Enter 1,2,3 or 4 for add,subtract,multiplication,division      respectively: "))
if var == 1:
 print "You chose to add.Lets add!! :)"
def main ():
 total = 0.0
 while True:
  number = int(raw_input('enter a number: '))
  if number == 0:
  total+=number
  break
  print 'the total is', total
```

main ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var = int(raw_input("Enter 1,2,3 or 4 for add,subtract,multiplication,division      respectively: "))
if var == 1:
    print "You chose to add.Lets add!! :)"

def main ():
    total = 0.0
    while True:
        number = float(raw_input('enter a number: '))
        total+=number
        if number == 0:
            break
    print 'the total is', total

main()
```

This will take any input and covert it to a float, add that to your total and, if the input is `0` then return your total.

To make this more flexible you can use the following change that will add all numbers (including `0`) and exit when nothing is entered by the user.

```
total = float(raw_input('enter a number: '))
while True:
    number = raw_input('enter a number: ')
    if number == '':
        break
    total+=float(number)
```

Comment: **What if i want to do the same for multiplication?** 


I read there is no built-in function for product of numbers in python like there is for addition i.e sum(number).and i cant use lists as the user input here is constantly changing.

Comment: @susan if you want to do the same for multiplication you can just change the `total += number` to `total *= number`

Comment: Tried it.but what should i change the last line to? i.e
    **print "the total is", total**
doesnt give the multiplied product. 

And the same loop doesnt work for subtraction with total-=number
it just "adds" up the "negative" values.

Comment: if it's just outputting `0.0` it's because your default value `total = 0.0` and multiplying anything by that, will always be `0.0`.

Comment: @susan - i've modified my second code to be even more flexible (not setting total to 0.0 at the start)

Comment: It works.What if i want to ask the user whether he wants to perform another calculation or not everytime the user makes a calculation and gets the answer?
I just want the code to run again from start everytime user performs calculation.

Comment: @susan - rather than explain that in the comments it's probably better if you open a new question